# Trying to login to RDP using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, rdp, vnc

I am trying to login to RDP using AS3 (air). I am doing ok, considering the lack of resources out there to understand the actual process.

I have gotten past the initial sending username, received a response from server, and I am now at initial request connection.

I am sending all my data and when sniffing traffic, I see that netmon is recognizing correctly what kind of packet I am sending (t125). I am *not* being disconnected by RDP and they send an `ack` packet - but I don't receive the response that I am expecting.

I have been cross referencing with `connectoid`, which is an open source RDP client. In the connection code, I am stuck where they write a mixture of little and big-endian integers.

When I look at the limited examples out there (more like packet dumps), I see that connection length for this process is 412, but my `bytearray` is more like 470.

I have converted `connectoid` methods to what I believe is correct, but with a mixture of endian type,  I am still unsure.

I am sorry if this is garbled, but I am trying my best to help you to help me. I will attach some code showing what I have tried to do in conversion.

```
public function sendMcsData(): void {
    trace("Secure.sendMcsData");
    var num_channels: int = 2;
    //RdpPacket_Localised dataBuffer = new RdpPacket_Localised(512);
    var hostlen: int = 2 * "myhostaddress.ath.cx".length;
    if (hostlen > 30) {
        hostlen = 30;
    }
    var length: int = 158;
    length += 76 + 12 + 4;
    length += num_channels * 12 + 8;
    dataBuffer.writeShort(5); /* unknown */
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0x14);
    dataBuffer.writeByte(0x7c); //set 8 is write byte //write short is setbigendian 16 //
    dataBuffer.writeShort(1);
    dataBuffer.writeShort(length | 0x8000); // remaining length
    dataBuffer.writeShort(8); // length?
    dataBuffer.writeShort(16);
    dataBuffer.writeByte(0);
    var b1: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    b1.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    b1.writeShort(0xc001);
    dataBuffer.writeBytes(b1);
    dataBuffer.writeByte(0);
    var b2: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    b2.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    b2.writeInt(0x61637544);
    dataBuffer.writeBytes(b2);
    //dataBuffer.setLittleEndian32(0x61637544); // "Duca" ?!
    dataBuffer.writeShort(length - 14 | 0x8000); // remaining length
    var b3: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    b3.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    // Client information
    b3.writeShort(SEC_TAG_CLI_INFO);
    b3.writeShort(true ? 212 : 136); // length
    b3.writeShort(true ? 4 : 1);
    b3.writeShort(8);
    b3.writeShort(600);
    b3.writeShort(1024);
    b3.writeShort(0xca01);
    b3.writeShort(0xaa03);
    b3.writeInt(0x809); //should be option.keybaortd layout just guessed 1
    b3.writeInt(true ? 2600 : 419); // or 0ece
    dataBuffer.writeBytes(b3);
    // // client
    // build? we
    // are 2600
    // compatible
    // :-)
    /* Unicode name of client, padded to 32 bytes */
    dataBuffer.writeMultiByte("myhost.ath.cx".toLocaleUpperCase(), "ISO");
    dataBuffer.position = dataBuffer.position + (30 - "myhost.ath.cx".toLocaleUpperCase()
        .length);
    var b4: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    b4.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    b4.writeInt(4);
    b4.writeInt(0);
    b4.writeInt(12);
    dataBuffer.writeBytes(b4);
    dataBuffer.position = dataBuffer.position + 64; /* reserved? 4 + 12 doublewords */
    var b5: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    b5.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    b5.writeShort(0xca01); // out_uint16_le(s, 0xca01);
    b5.writeShort(true ? 1 : 0);
    if (true) //Options.use_rdp5)
    {
        b5.writeInt(0); // out_uint32(s, 0);
        b5.writeByte(24); // out_uint8(s, g_server_bpp);
        b5.writeShort(0x0700); // out_uint16_le(s, 0x0700);
        b5.writeByte(0); // out_uint8(s, 0);
        b5.writeInt(1); // out_uint32_le(s, 1);
        b5.position = b5.position + 64;
        b5.writeShort(SEC_TAG_CLI_4); // out_uint16_le(s,
        // SEC_TAG_CLI_4);
        b5.writeShort(12); // out_uint16_le(s, 12);
        b5.writeInt(false ? 0xb : 0xd); // out_uint32_le(s,
        // g_console_session
        // ?
        // 0xb
        // :
        // 9);
        b5.writeInt(0); // out_uint32(s, 0);
    }
    // Client encryption settings //
    b5.writeShort(SEC_TAG_CLI_CRYPT);
    b5.writeShort(true ? 12 : 8); // length
    // if(Options.use_rdp5) dataBuffer.setLittleEndian32(Options.encryption ?
    // 0x1b : 0); // 128-bit encryption supported
    // else
    b5.writeInt(true ? (false ? 0xb : 0x3) : 0);
    if (true) b5.writeInt(0); // unknown
    if (true && (num_channels > 0)) {
        trace(("num_channels is " + num_channels));
        b5.writeShort(SEC_TAG_CLI_CHANNELS); // out_uint16_le(s,
        // SEC_TAG_CLI_CHANNELS);
        b5.writeShort(num_channels * 12 + 8); // out_uint16_le(s,
        // g_num_channels
        // * 12
        // + 8);
        // //
        // length
        b5.writeInt(num_channels); // out_uint32_le(s,
        // g_num_channels);
        // // number of
        // virtual
        // channels
        dataBuffer.writeBytes(b5);
        trace("b5 is bigendin" + (b5.endian == Endian.BIG_ENDIAN));
        for (var i: int = 0; i < num_channels; i++) {
            dataBuffer.writeMultiByte("testtes" + i, "ascii"); //, 8); // out_uint8a(s,
            // g_channels[i].name,
            // 8);
            dataBuffer.writeInt(0x40000000); // out_uint32_be(s,
            // g_channels[i].flags);
        }
    }
    //socket.
    //buffer.markEnd();
    //return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Can you capture the offending packet from a known good RDP client and compare against the packets you're curious about? It may be a bug within how you're encoding a segment of your byte array.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by you are at the "initial request connection", please?  The initial request should have been passed already for you to login so it's unclear exactly what state you are stuck at. You have sent your Connection Request (0xe0) and received your Confirmation (0xd0) and now you are at "connect-initial" phase? Or somewhere further down the line of events?  Is the packet that you generating in the above code the "MCS: connect-initial" packet?

Comment: Silly question but have you tried to manually RDP into that box to see that it works? there could be something happening to prevent login like a banner "this machine is for authorized use only blah blah"

Comment: Don't know if you've done this already but you should take a look at the source code for KRDC ([link](https://www.kde.org/applications/internet/krdc/)) or freerdp ([link](http://www.freerdp.com/)). They might provide great insight to your problem.

Comment: As it seems from connectoid source code, data in these packets is BER encoded; you should write a couple of functions to ease yourself from manually crafting packet data, and to help your (and our) debug of your code.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the majority of the buffer is little endian, but several bytes at its start are expected to be big endian numbers of 16 bit (short). This means, you have to write data in little endian as if it'll be interpreted as big endian. In order to convert the data from big endian to little endian, you can use a temporary `ByteArray` that has its endian set to big, write data in it, then call `writeBytes()` on your main buffer array, then clear the temporary big endian array. Writing constants can be done manually, since you can shift the byte order yourself, say when you are writing `0x0005` in big endian as short, you just do write `0x0500` as little endian instead. You seemingly wrote the code with the extraneous `dataBuffer` with endian being big, so you know this technique. Still, it's better that you will just produce a proper `dataBuffer` in the function. I'm attempting to fix your code below basing on the `connectoid` code I have downloaded, so that it will return a properly formed `ByteArray` with endian being little - this only matters if you'll read ordered data from it, not when you read bytes.

```
public function sendMcsData(): ByteArray {
    trace("Secure.sendMcsData");
    var num_channels: int = 2;
    var dataBuffer:ByteArray=new ByteArray(); //RdpPacket_Localised dataBuffer = new RdpPacket_Localised(512);
    // it's better to build the data buffer in the function, as in java, otherwise you can receive interference
    dataBuffer.endian=Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN; // for clarity
    var hostlen: int = 2 * "myhost.ath.cx".length; // hardcoded? TODO FIX
    if (hostlen > 30) {
        hostlen = 30;
    }
    var length: int = 158;
    length += 76 + 12 + 4; // Options.use_rdp5 is true, apparently
    length += num_channels * 12 + 8;
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0x0500); // writing big-endian 0x5 *unknown*
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0x1400); // writing big-endian 0x14
    dataBuffer.writeByte(0x7c); //set 8 is write byte 
    //write short is setbigendian 16 //
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0x0100); // writing big-endian 0x01
    var be:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
    be.endian=Endian.BIG_ENDIAN; // create big-endian array for the data that's not static
    be.writeShort(length | 0x8000); // remaining length
    dataBuffer.writeBytes(be);
    be.clear(); // so that extra writing will not spoil the array
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0x0800); // writing big-endian 0x08 (length?)
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0x1000); // writing big-endian 16 (0x10)
    dataBuffer.writeByte(0);
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0xc001); // this one is little endian by default
    dataBuffer.writeByte(0);
    dataBuffer.writeUnsignedInt(0x61637544);
    //dataBuffer.setLittleEndian32(0x61637544); // "Duca" ?!
    be.writeShort((length - 14) | 0x8000); // remaining length
    dataBuffer.writeBytes(be);
    be.clear();
    dataBuffer.writeShort(SEC_TAG_CLI_INFO);
    dataBuffer.writeShort(212); // length
    dataBuffer.writeShort(4);
    dataBuffer.writeShort(8);
    dataBuffer.writeShort(600); // Options.width
    dataBuffer.writeShort(1024); // Options.height
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0xca01);
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0xaa03);
    dataBuffer.writeInt(0x0409); //Options.keylayout, default English/US - fixed
    dataBuffer.writeInt(2600); // or 0ece
    dataBuffer.writeBytes(b3);
    // // client
    // build? we
    // are 2600
    // compatible
    // :-)
    /* Unicode name of client, padded to 32 bytes */
    var targetPos:int=dataBuffer.position+32; // to account for padding
    dataBuffer.writeMultiByte("myhost.ath.cx".toLocaleUpperCase(), "UTF-16"); 
    // buffer.outUnicodeString(Options.hostname.toUpperCase(), hostlen);
    // apparently encoding is used "Unicode" that is UTF-16. If that will not work, set UTF-8 here
    // and by all means check what is on the wire when you connect via conventional RDP

    dataBuffer.position = targetPos;
    // this seems to be your mistake in converting position truncate, 
    // as position after writing already accounts for the writing been processed.
    // This line alone can be the source of size discrepancy you observe.
    dataBuffer.writeInt(4);
    dataBuffer.writeInt(0);
    dataBuffer.writeInt(12);
    dataBuffer.position = dataBuffer.position + 64; // /* reserved? 4 + 12 doublewords */
    // note, if the position wouldn't shift forward, write zeroes manually
    dataBuffer.writeShort(0xca01); // out_uint16_le(s, 0xca01);
    dataBuffer.writeShort(1);
    if (true) //Options.use_rdp5)
    {
        dataBuffer.writeInt(0); // out_uint32(s, 0);
        dataBuffer.writeByte(24); // out_uint8(s, g_server_bpp);
        dataBuffer.writeShort(0x0700); // out_uint16_le(s, 0x0700);
        dataBuffer.writeByte(0); // out_uint8(s, 0);
        dataBuffer.writeInt(1); // out_uint32_le(s, 1);
        dataBuffer.position = dataBuffer.position + 64;
        dataBuffer.writeShort(SEC_TAG_CLI_4); // out_uint16_le(s,
        // SEC_TAG_CLI_4);
        dataBuffer.writeShort(12); // out_uint16_le(s, 12);
        dataBuffer.writeInt(0xd); // out_uint32_le(s,
        // g_console_session
        // ?
        // 0xb
        // :
        // 9);
        // the comments say 9, but the code says 0xd - leaving 0xd in place
        // Options.console_session is hardcoded false
        dataBuffer.writeInt(0); // out_uint32(s, 0);
    }
    // Client encryption settings //
    dataBuffer.writeShort(SEC_TAG_CLI_CRYPT);
    dataBuffer.writeShort(12); // length
    // if(Options.use_rdp5) dataBuffer.setLittleEndian32(Options.encryption ?
    // 0x1b : 0); // 128-bit encryption supported
    // else
    dataBuffer.writeInt(true ? (false ? 0xb : 0x3) : 0);
    dataBuffer.writeInt(0); // unknown
    if (true && (num_channels > 0)) {
        trace(("num_channels is", num_channels));
        dataBuffer.writeShort(SEC_TAG_CLI_CHANNELS); // out_uint16_le(s,
        // SEC_TAG_CLI_CHANNELS);
        dataBuffer.writeShort(num_channels * 12 + 8); // out_uint16_le(s,
        // g_num_channels
        // * 12
        // + 8);
        // //
        // length
        dataBuffer.writeInt(num_channels); // out_uint32_le(s,
        // g_num_channels);
        // // number of
        // virtual
        // channels
        for (var i: int = 0; i < num_channels; i++) {
            targetPos=dataBuffer.position+8; // account for padding/truncation
            dataBuffer.writeMultiByte("testtes" + i, "ascii"); //, 8); // out_uint8a(s,
            // g_channels[i].name,
            // 8);
            dataBuffer.position=targetPos;
            dataBuffer.writeInt(0x00000040); // out_uint32_be(s,
            // g_channels[i].flags);
            // writing big-endian 0x40000000
        }
    }
    trace("sendMCSData: Data buffer length is",dataBuffer.length); // debug
    return dataBuffer;
}
```

Hope this helps.